# IText 7 not rendering bootstrap's input prepend/appends inline

Tags: c#, bootstrap-4, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I'm trying out IText7's HtmlConverter for C# and I'm having a little trouble getting it to render bootstrap's inputs correctly.  Instead of them rendering the input with the prepend/append inline, it's rendering them onto separate lines.  Here's the code I'm using

First I'm getting the html from the site

```
public static string GetHtml() {
     WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/input-group/");

    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream(); 
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();

    return responseFromServer;
}
```

Then I'm pushing it through an altered version of the demo the html into the itext's responsive html converter found here: https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/pdfhtml-responsive-design

```
public static void TestOne() {
    string html = Helpers.GetHtml();
    using (FileStream pdfDest = File.Open($"{Helpers.dataDir}\\IText-output.pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(pdfDest);
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);

        // Set the result to be tagged
        pdfDoc.SetTagged();
        pdfDoc.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);
        // Set media device description details
        MediaDeviceDescription mediaDescription = new MediaDeviceDescription(MediaType.SCREEN);
        mediaDescription.SetWidth(CssUtils.ParseAbsoluteLength(PageSize.A4.GetWidth().ToString()));
        ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
        converterProperties.SetMediaDeviceDescription(mediaDescription);
        converterProperties.SetBaseUri("https://getbootstrap.com/");
        HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(html, pdfDoc, converterProperties);
    }
}
```

It's rendering the pdf, but the the inputs are rendering like this

[image]

while they render like this in a browser

[image]
Am I using this incorrectly?

Comment: Bootstrap uses `display: flex` to position those elements in one line, but pdfHTML does not support `display: flex` at this point. So this is a missing feature basically. One day it will be there.

Comment: Even with their responsive design api? 
 https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/pdfhtml-responsive-design